# problems to format current date (-1month) to YYYYMMDD

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am developing a batch script that takes the **current date -1 month** and formats it as **YYYYMMDD**, but when i execute my code the final variable has just the year (without the month concatenated). Could you please help me to find the error?

The code is the following:

```
echo off &setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET _test=%date%
SET _month=%_test:~4,2%
SET _day=01
SET search_year=%_test:~10,4%


IF "%_month%" EQU 1 (
        set search_month=12
        set /a search_year= %seach_year% -1
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 2 (
        set search_month=1
)
IF "%_month%" EQU 3 (
        set search_month=2
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 4 (
        set search_month=3
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 5 (
        set search_month=4
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 6 (
        set search_month=5
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 7 (
        set search_month=06
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 8 (
        set search_month=07
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 9 (
        set search_month=08
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 10 (
        set search_month=09
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 11 (
        set search_month=10
)

IF "%_month%" EQU 12 (
        set search_month=11
)


echo Month-1 is %search_month%
set /a total = %search_year%%search_month%
echo total is %total%
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your month comparisons are incorrect. Getting month from `%_test:~4,2%` means that the current month (May) is returned as `05`, not `5`.

Also, when there are quotes on one side of a comparison, there must be quotes on the other side, because batch includes the quotes when comparing. As a result of both of these things, search_month is never being set. Your comparisons should look like this:

```
IF "%_month%" EQU "05" (
    set search_month=4
)
```

That said, 12 basically identical comparisons is a ton of redundant code, and you can make it way simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET _test=%date%
SET _month=%_test:~4,2%
SET _day=01
SET search_year=%_test:~10,4%

if "%_month%" equ "01" (
    set search_month=12
    set /a search_year-=1
) else (
    REM Remove any zero-padding so that months are not considered octal.
    REM We do this by putting a 1 in front of %_month% and then subtracting 100
    REM because set /a returns in decimal.
    REM And then we subtract 1 because we're getting the previous month.
    set /a search_month=1%_month%-100-1

    REM Replace the zero-padding since you want YYYYMM format.
    REM Use delayed expansion here because search_month was created inside
    REM of a code block.
    if !search_month! lss 10 set search_month=0!search_month!
)

echo Month-1 is !search_month!
set total=%search_year%!search_month!
echo total is %total%
```

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for! thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: and what about if i want to execute this just the 15th of the month?

Comment: @thartaras - well, the code you initially provided doesn't factor in the day at all, but based on the fact that you've got a `_day` variable, I'm going to go out on a limb and say change that value to 15. But that's just a guess because your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

No need to place quotes around `%_month%` 
Here is what you want,

```
echo off &setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET _test=%date%
SET _month=%_test:~4,2%
SET _day=01
SET search_year=%_test:~10,4%


IF %_month% EQU 1 (
        set search_month=12
        set /a search_year= %seach_year% -1
)

IF %_month% EQU 2 (
        set search_month=01
)
IF %_month% EQU 3 (
        set search_month=02
)

IF %_month% EQU 4 (
        set search_month=03
)

IF %_month% EQU 5 (
        set search_month=04
)

IF %_month% EQU 6 (
        set search_month=05
)

IF %_month% EQU 7 (
        set search_month=06
)

IF %_month% EQU 8 (
        set search_month=07
)

IF %_month% EQU 9 (
        set search_month=08
)

IF %_month% EQU 10 (
        set search_month=09
)

IF %_month% EQU 11 (
        set search_month=10
)

IF %_month% EQU 12 (
        set search_month=11
)


echo Month-1 is %search_month%
set /a total = %search_year%%search_month%
echo total is %total%
```